# Concatenating Firstname and lastname as Name and then ommit Firtname and LastName in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, excel-import

I have a problem statement as below :

From a DB source I have a table which has data related to Person. Out of which 3 columns are as Title, FirstName, LastName and I want to replace this as Name before actually putting it to the destination.

I tried using derived column but it gives me Name (ie. concatenation of Title, FirstName, LastName) and individual these columns as well.

Please suggest.

Comment: Both answer are correct, why not accepting any one until now?

Answer (score 2):

You can just ignore the original columns when mapping to destination or you can right click on the destination (or any transformation after the derive column) -> show advanced editor -> input columns and then uncheck the columns that you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, your solution is good, even if individuals columns still appearing, it is not necessary to map them, to your destination, just ignore them.*

**Other method**

If using an `OLEDB Source` select `Source type` as `SQL Command` and use the following command:

```
SELECT [Title] + ' ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] AS Name, ...
FROM MyTable
```

If using `Excel Source` select `Source type` as `SQL Command` and use the following command:

```
 SELECT [Title] + ' ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] AS Name
 FROM   [Sheet1$]
```